# Trying to get row index value when clicking on a specific row td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a table like this, and I need to get a row index value when clicking on a particular cell in a row. I don't need to get any values when clicking on rest of the cells.

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td>
   </tr>
      <td>3</td><td>3</td><td>3</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my jQuery code goes. I am getting row index value perfectly

```
$(function(){

    $("table tr").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).index());
});
});
```

But I need like when clicking on particular cell only. Here I used third cell.

```
//$("table tr").find('td').eq(2).click(function() {
```

Comment: click on cell  and use `$(this).parent().index()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `closest('tr')`.

```js
$(function(){

    $("table tr td").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).closest('tr').index());
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td>
   </tr>
      <td>3</td><td>3</td><td>3</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td><td>1</td><td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td><td>3</td><td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>


     $(function(){

         $("table tr").each(function(){
            $(this).find("td").eq(2).click(function(){
                console.log($(this).text());
            });

         });
     });
```

use this code will help you

http://jsfiddle.net/sc6Ld40v/

Comment: this doesn't answer what OP asked. `text()` has nothing to do with indexing